# Creating a django signal for user details updation

Tags: django

I am working on a django project, where I want to implement a signal which should be called when some user address is changed. I have seen the built-in signals but they do not seem to work in my case, because if i use save that will be called in other save events as well and though I am able to create a custom signal, I could not find out, how should I call this ?

Please suggest.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Start by defining a custom signal. A custom signal here is a sub class of `django.dispatch.Signal`. This code can live in `app/signals.py`.

```
from django.dispatch import Signal
user_address_changed = Signal(providing_args=["user"])
```

Next, make sure you send this signal when your user's address is changed. Depending on how you have defined `User` and `Address` this can be done in different places. Let us assume that there is a view that lets users update their `Address` models. This code is presumably in `app/views.py`.

```
from app import signals

def update_address(request, *args, **kwargs):
    # all the changes go well.
    signals.user_address_changed.send(sender=None, user=request.user)
    # Render to template etc.
```

Now you need to set up a receiver for this signal.

```
from app.signals import user_address_changed

def handle_user_address_change(sender, **kwargs):
    """Trap the signal and do whatever is needed"""
    user = kwargs['user']
    # Write to log, update db, send mail etc.

user_address_changed.connect(handle_user_address_change)
```

**Update**

(After reading comment; the OP explains that there is no separate view that updates address) In that case you can try to override `User.save()` to send out this signal. I say "try" because I do not know if you are using your own `User` class or `auth.User`.

Comment: thanks for your reply manoj, this one would work fine for the front-end user updates. But if we change the address through the admin panel, this view would not be called and hence this signal would not be sent.

Comment: its a separate model with user as a foreign key.. so i guess User.save() is not possible in this case?

Answer (score 1):

You may appreciate django-signalqueue:

https://github.com/fish2000/django-signalqueue

It's an extension to the stock signal dispatcher that provides an AsyncSignal class. AsyncSignal callbacks can be executed on a separate worker thread -- you can control the specific behavior of the asynchronous listeners you define.

(full disclosure: I wrote it.)